# How to change the properties of a class css without ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css

*I am making a user control with properties that can change*

I have a HTML (.aspx):

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li id="li_id" runat="server" class="myStyle" visible="false"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(My first li is false that the other will be added dynamically and want to make sure there is at least one reference css class)

my codebehind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fotos.Count(); i++)
{
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath((fotos[i]))))
    {
        content_slider_inside.InnerHtml += @"<li id='img" + i.ToString() + "'><IMG SRC='" + fotos[i] + "' HEIGHT='490PX' /></li>";
        navigation.InnerHtml += "<li class='myStyle' runat='server'><a href='#img" + (i+1).ToString() + "'>" + (i+1).ToString() + "</a></li>";
    }
}
```

My CSS (.css)

```
.myStyle
{
    /*empty*/
}
```

**How i add my style properties without using the ID code?** (since it is generated dinicamente)
for example:

```
myStyle["background-color"]="red";
```

for all generated dynamically change li css property

I'm NOT interested to solve it with javascript or jquery

thank you so much

Comment: Do you want (a) change style dynamically, (b) change style for just one element, (c) change particular property of a style for one element?

Comment: I want change the elemntes with css class ("myStyle") becouse I am making a user control with properties that can change

Comment: So why changing CSS file itself does not work for you?

Comment: I do not want to change the css file, I include the properties of the li elements dynamically specifying all the background, border, ...

Comment: Render styles inline? (added sample to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Using "class" attribute and CSS is good way of styling elements. It is not clear what you trying to do "dynamically", but maybe simply changing you CSS is enough (and you don't really need invisible element if the only reason is to mention class for CSS):

```
.myStyle
{
    background-color:"red";
}
```

If you want to style them individually you can inline in HTML directly:

```
navigation.InnerHtml += "<li style='background-color:red;' ...
```

Note: it would be easier if you build control tree instead of using InnerHtml property. At least don't specify `runat='server'` since there is no value in it when using InnerHtml property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a great variety of CSS Selectors to do that http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 0):

two answers to my problem:

as mentioned by the user Alexei Levenkov generating generic HTML controls HtmlGenericControl

```
for (int i = 0; i < fotos.Count(); i++)
{
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath((fotos[i]))))
    {
        content_slider_inside.InnerHtml += @"<li id='img" + (i + 1).ToString() + "'><IMG SRC='" + fotos[i] + "' HEIGHT='490PX' /></li>";
        //navigation.InnerHtml += "<li id='item" + (i+1).ToString() + "' runat='server' class='menu_item'><a href='#img" + (i+1).ToString() + "'>" + (i+1).ToString() + "</a></li>";

        HtmlGenericControl a = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        a.Attributes["href"] = "#img" + (i+1).ToString();
        a.InnerHtml = (i + 1).ToString();

        HtmlGenericControl c = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        c.ID = "item" + (i+1).ToString();
        c.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        c.Attributes["class"] = "menu_item";
        c.Controls.Add(a);

        navigation.Controls.Add(c);

        id_imgs.Add("img" + (i+1).ToString());
        id_items.Add("item" + (i+1).ToString());
    }
}
```

and then I can manually access their styles through his property

```
foreach(string i in id_items)
{
    HtmlGenericControl liItem = (HtmlGenericControl)navigation.FindControl(i);
    if (liItem != null)
    {
        if (menu_Item_Fondo != null)
            liItem.Style["background-color"] = menu_Item_Fondo;
        if (menu_Item_Hover_Fondo != null)
        {
            StringBuilder style = new StringBuilder();
            style.AppendLine(".navigation li a:hover { ");
            style.AppendLine(String.Format(" color: {0};", menu_Item_Hover_TextColor));
            style.AppendLine(String.Format(" background-color: {0};", menu_Item_Hover_Fondo));
            style.AppendLine("} ");
            style_menu_item.InnerText = style.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

To use the hover dynamically add one label style

```
<div>
    <style id="style_menu_item" runat="server" class="class_style"></style>
    <ul>
        <li id="li_id" runat="server" class="myStyle" visible="false"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm Happy!